# Getting a user's position in a queue table is too slow

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a MariaDB table that looks like this:

```
+--------+--------+--------+---------------------+
| realm  |  key2  | userId |        date         |
+--------+--------+--------+---------------------+
|    AB3 |    123 |      1 | 2017-08-04 17:30:00 |
|    AB3 |    124 |      1 | 2017-08-04 17:30:00 |
|    AB3 |    125 |      1 | 2017-08-04 17:30:00 |
|    XY7 |     97 |      2 | 2017-08-04 17:35:00 |
|    XY7 |     98 |      2 | 2017-08-04 17:35:00 |
|    XY7 |     99 |      2 | 2017-08-04 17:35:00 |
|    AB3 |    110 |      3 | 2017-08-04 17:40:00 |
|    AB3 |    111 |      3 | 2017-08-04 17:40:00 |
+--------+--------+--------+---------------------+

PRIMARY_KEY (realm, key2)
INDEX (realm, userId)
INDEX (date)
```

This table operates as some sort of queue for processing user actions. Basically a server always takes the oldest data from this table, processes it and deletes it from this table. Each realm has its own server processing this queue.

Now I want to find out a user's position in queue *for that realm*. So, using the example above, when I request the position for userId 3 in realm 'AB3', I want to get the result `2` because only one other user (userId 1) is to be processed earlier for realm AB3.

(The row `key2` *might* be irrelevant in this example. I only included it because it is part of the primary key which may make it relevant for finding a good solution)

Here is the SQL schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `queue` (
  `realm` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `key2` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `userId` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `queue` (`realm`, `key2`, `userId`, `date`) VALUES
('AB3', 110, 3, '2017-08-04 17:40:00'),
('AB3', 111, 3, '2017-08-04 17:40:00'),
('AB3', 123, 1, '2017-08-04 17:30:00'),
('AB3', 124, 1, '2017-08-04 17:30:00'),
('AB3', 125, 1, '2017-08-04 17:30:00'),
('XY7', 97, 2, '2017-08-04 17:35:00'),
('XY7', 98, 2, '2017-08-04 17:35:00'),
('XY7', 99, 2, '2017-08-04 17:35:00');

ALTER TABLE `queue`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`realm`,`key2`),
  ADD KEY `ru` (`realm`,`userId`) USING BTREE,
  ADD KEY `date` (`date`);
```

I came up with this query that seems to work but is pretty slow (~3 seconds) on a table with 10,000,000 entries:

```
SELECT (COUNT(DISTINCT `realm`, `userId`)+1) `position`
FROM `queue`
WHERE `realm` = 'AB3'
AND `date` < (
  SELECT `date`
  FROM `queue`
  WHERE `realm` = 'AB3' AND `userId` = 3
  GROUP BY `realm`, `userId`
)
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb04fd/9/0

`EXPLAIN EXTENDED` of this query:

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------------+-----------------+------------+---------+-------+---------+----------+------------------------------------------+--+
| id | select_type | table |    type     |  possible_keys  |    key     | key_len |  ref  |  rows   | filtered |                  Extra                   |  |
+----+-------------+-------+-------------+-----------------+------------+---------+-------+---------+----------+------------------------------------------+--+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | queue | ref         | PRIMARY,ru,date | PRIMARY    |     767 | const | 5266123 |   100.00 | Using where                              |  |
|  2 | SUBQUERY    | queue | index_merge | PRIMARY,ru      | ru,PRIMARY | 771,767 |       |     496 |    75.00 | Using intersect(ru,PRIMARY); Using where |  |
+----+-------------+-------+-------------+-----------------+------------+---------+-------+---------+----------+------------------------------------------+--+
```

Do you have any ideas how I can optimize this query to run faster on a table with like 10,000,000 entries?

---

Other queries that are run on this table:

```
SELECT `m`.*
FROM `queue` `m`
JOIN (
    SELECT `m`.*
    FROM `queue` `m`
    WHERE `m`.`realm` = ?
    ORDER BY `date` ASC
    LIMIT 1
) `mm` ON `m`.`realm` = `mm`.`realm` AND `m`.`userId` = `mm`.`userId`;
```

and

```
DELETE FROM `queue` WHERE `realm` = ? AND `userId` = ?;
```

How could I optimize my indexes?

Comment: It's not particularly slow- but it's not particularly accurate either - unless there's a piece of information about dates which you've not told us :-(

Comment: Best index for the the subquery is `(realm, userId, date)` or `(userId, realm, date)`. Best index for the outer query is `(realm, date, userId)` - but it might enough without `userId`. I'm surprised that it only takes 3 seconds with the given indexes. Please check how long it takes for the subquery only.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel The subquery alone runs in 0.002 seconds. Using the one from wargre's answer pretty much takes the same time. It looks like only the outer query needs improvement. Adding an index on `(realm, date)` could probably speed it up significantly. -- I also edited the other 2 queries I have to use frequently on this table. Given these queries, what indexes would you recommend to use for this table? (For insert reasons I will need a PK or UNIQUE on `(realm, key2)`)

Comment: @user2015253 Can you tell some numbers? .. Number of distinct realms/server. Average number of ditinct userIds. Average number of inserts per day.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Distinct realms: 10+. Distinct userIds: 100k. Inserts per day: Hard to estimate, probably 50m+ minimum. It's worth noting that a userId is only unique to a certain realm, so userId 1 is a totally different user for realm A and realm B. If it matters, the server has a strong CPU, 256 GB RAM, but only uses HDD for storage (because SSD simply isn't big enough and couldn't survive all the writes and deletes that are going on in this database). I/O does not seem to be a bottleneck right now though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel like something wrong with the table DDL. Anyway, i would have rewriten your query like :

```
SELECT (COUNT(DISTINCT `userId`)+1) `position`
FROM `queue`
WHERE `realm` = 'AB3'
    AND `date` < (
        SELECT min(`date`)
        FROM `queue`
        WHERE `realm` = 'AB3' AND `userId` = 3
    )
```

and perhaps have a really specific index for this query like :

```
index (realm, date)
```

You can try the sheety index

```
index (realm, date, userId)
```

but not even sure it will be faster that the previous one.

Comment: I would have do something like (realm, userId, date) as primary key, with something to ensure date is always distinct (per userId).  (in fact I lie, I would have taken a message broker to do this ;) )

Comment: I edited the other 2 queries that I frequently use into the original post. How would you optimize indexes, given that I want to use those 2 queries aswell as the one from your answer?

Comment: If you added the (realm, date) index, your 1st query cannot be indexed more. The delete use the (realm, userid) index, so nothing more to do.

Comment: Why would an additional index prevent my first query from using indexes?

Comment: I mean, the ideal indexes for your 1st query are (realm, date) and (realm, userId) If you have those, you cannot do more

Comment: Alright, I will need a `(realm, date)` index then. Thanks!

Comment: @user2015253 Please check [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fe65ac/1). It might not fit your data very well, but I think you can reduce the runtime by only rewriting your query (as in this answer). Note that this query may return a different result - But it's the correct one, since your original subquery returns a "random" date.